# How to create Quarter Cylinder

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I am new to blender and couldn't find how I could make a quarter cylinder. I first tried starting with a cube and subdividing two sides. But this subdivided the two sides into two directions, not just one. Then I tried starting with a cylinder and deleting the 3/4 the vertices which did not result in something useful either. What is the standard way to go?

Comment: It would be useful if you showed an image or wrote a few steps as to how you went about deleting the vertices and how that didn't do what you want as this is what most people will suggest.

Comment: In edit mode I selected the vertices of the top half and bottom right fourth of the cylinder. Then I pressed x and hit delete vertices. The thing is here that the end's of the cylinder disappeared, only the curved side remained.

Comment: Related techniques at http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19630/5486

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a circle with number of vertices that is multiple of 4 (eg 8,12,16...), select all vertices, press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to merge at center, delete unwanted vertices and extrude again to desired height.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguiseGraphics I think you couldn't write this in a shorter way, excellent even without images=)

Answer (score 19):

Although there are many ways to do so, you CAN create a quarter cylinder from a cube:

1. Select the cube object, Go to **Edit mode**;
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to bevel the selected edge, roll the mouse wheel to adjust segements;
3. <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices, then <kbd>W</kbd> -> *Remove Doubles*.

[image]

---

**Tip:**

To ensure the maximum bevel extent on that edge, you can consider either one of the following ways:

1. After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, you can see the available operations on the 3D View header (with shortcuts). So, you can then press <kbd>M</kbd> three times to switch bevel mode to **Percent**, then type **100** for a maximum Offset percent.

[image]

2. You can also do it after confirming the bevel operation, from either the lowerleft of the Tooblar (<kbd>T</kbd>) or a seperate popup menu(<kbd>F6</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: That is a really nice gif! Is there a special software for creating gifs like this? Just asking because I've seen quite a few here on blender.SE!

Comment: I personally use Ulead GIF Animator, which is not a freeware however. I'm looking for another FOSS one too. I remember @gandalf3 mentioned a cool one. Just forgot the name.

Comment: Thanks! BTW: In my version (as well as in the docs) it says the shortcut is [crtl]+[b]

Comment: Typo was fixed. :D

Comment: @flawr You might be interested in [this](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/522/placing-gifs-in-text) meta post.

Comment: Moving the mouse past the maximum amount of bevel wraps around to zero bevel. Is there a way to be sure we're getting the max bevel?

Comment: The free one gandalf uses is LICEcap

Comment: @ajwood Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @LeonCheung #1 isn't in v2.71.. #2 does the trick for me though!

Comment: It seems the Linux PPA was abandoned a while back.. I haven't seen a new feature in months :(

Answer (score 12):

Another way would be to use the [*Spin-Tool*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/meshes/tools/spin.html?#spin)

Starting with a plane, here in top view notice the position of the 3D cursor:

[image]

Switch to right view and invoke the spin tool <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I personally like this one, since it can generate pie with any sector degree, not just a quarter. :)

Comment: This is another very nice solution! Can you tell me, how did you achieve that everything sticks right to the grid points?

Comment: @flawr the default setting is 90° so the gif seems to snap, the plane rotates around the 3D cursor.

Answer (score 9):

1. In *Edit Mode* select 3/4 of the vertices of a Circle and delete the vertices <kbd>X</kbd> > *Vertices*.
   [image: delete menu in edit mode]
2. Change the [snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/meshes/uv/editing.html?#snap) mode to *Vertex*.
3. Extrude the end vertex along the Y axis, <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> until it snaps to the other end of the curve.
   [image: extruding a vertex]
4. Select all the vertices with <kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>; then make a face with <kbd>F</kbd>
5. Without changing the selection press <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> to extrude along the Z axis.

This is the final shape.
[image: final shape]

Comment: This is my usual method. Easiest way to do the selection is with circle select (C?) and paint the ones you don't want. Though there is an invert selection function too...

Comment: @StarWeaver I use border select, but any way that is most comfortable to you works.