# modeling cube into cylinder

Tags: modeling, transforms

I am new to blender and currently trying to learn modeling techniques. I would like to change a square into cylinder. From what I've read the easiest way would be to use the array modifier and warp it around a bezier circle and then extrude that object. But I was wondering if there are any tutorials on how to do this using only transforms and only a few subdivides....To be specific, I'm trying to make a pillar object from a cube

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Quarter Cylinder](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19172/how-to-create-quarter-cylinder)

Comment: @LeonCheung not so much duplicate as related and pertinent, good to reference here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I took the liberty to simplify the provided answers.

---

> Leon Cheung-method:

**Bevel** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> edges and use **Clamp Overlap** <kbd>C</kbd> while beveling.

Example:

[image]

---

> stacker-method:

Enable LoopTools Addon that comes with Blender.

Then, use: <kbd>W</kbd> > <kbd>LoopTools</kbd> > <kbd>Circle</kbd> - Even though sometimes you need to manually adjust some angles.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Method 1

Starting with a scaled default cube you could add a loop cuts along all axis' <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> like so:

[image]

Then select the middle loop cut ans scale it <kbd>S</kbd>

[image]

Open the specials menu <kbd>W</kbd> and select *LoopTools/Circle* Note that the Looptools must be enabled in the *User Preferences / Addon*

[image]

Result with a *Subsurf Modifier* added:

[image]

### Method 2

(Suggested by Leon Cheung)
Select the edges of the scaled cube like so:

[image]

Press Ctrl-B for Bevel adjust the radius by moving the mouse and add cuts by turning the mouse wheel.

[image]

Result after adding and scaling a loop cut around z-axis and sub-surfing:

[image]

Comment: Could also do scale to circle, I believe the key is shift+alt+S, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: @user1894167 lol, I misread your question and thought I've read pillow but you were asking for pillar.

Comment: @stacker, i just didnt subsurf and added more bevel sections to your method to get a pillar

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would go to create a cylinder:

Here's my cube;

[image]

I add a **Subdivision Surface** modifier. (change the number of divisions based on how smooth you want your cylinder to look.

[image]

Here is what the cube now looks like.

[image]

Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into *edit mode* and select the top and bottom faces (edge select)

[image]

Hit <kbd>N</kbd> to open the properties window. look for the *Mean Crease* option under *Transform*. Set it all the way up (1.00).

[image]

Here's what it'll look like.

[image]

Just <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of edit made and you've got a wonderful cylinder. (apply the subdivision surface if needed.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That looks like a better way of doing it just using transforms and subdiv like i wanted.

Comment: @user1894167 I am sorry but this method does not produce a cylinder. Subsurfaced surfaces are not round - the subsurfaced cube is not a sphere nor this is a cylinder. The bevel or verts-to-circle are both accurate methods.

Comment: @user1894167 I agree with Jerryno, the final result is not strictly a cylinder. Whatever, it would be okay assuming you needn't a perfect one.