# How to make a half cylinder?

Tags: modeling

I am having a tough time building a half cylinder and have not found any tutorial showing me how to do that.

Comment: Related: [How to create Quarter Cylinder](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19172/2217)

Answer (score 17):

Go into top view (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>), enter edit mode, press <kbd>B</kbd>, and box select half the vertices. Then press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Vertices*. You may need to rotate so that the edges align to the grid properly. Once youhave done that, select the four inner vertices and press <kbd>F</kbd>. <kbd>Alt</kbd> right-click on the end edges and press <kbd>F</kbd> to make faces for them as well.

[image: Half Cylinder GIF]

Answer (score 11):

All the steps below are in front view <kbd>NumPad 1</kbd>.

1. Add a plane
2. In edit mode move the plane 1 unit along the x axis, <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> `1`.
3. Spin the plane with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> or from the Tool Shelf > *Tool* tab *Spin*.
4. Set the *Angle* to -180°.

[image: animated gif]

Answer (score 6):

Just to have more options, here's how to do it with curves:

- On top view add a Curve->Circle.
- Enter edit mode.
- With all the handles selected press <kbd>V</kbd> to set the control handle type to **Free**
- Delete the bottom control point.
- Select the lower control points and using <kbd>V</kbd> convert the handles to **vector** You should have a curve with the shape of half circle.
- Exit Edit mode.

[image]

- Add a **Bezier Curve**
- Enter Edit Mode and set the handles to **Vector**, so you end up with a straight line.

[image]

- Exit Edit Mode and on the properties window set the Bezeir curve to use the Bezier Circle as **Bevel Object**.
- You can then choose to fill the caps or not.

[image]

The main advantage of this workflow is that the curves remain editable and independent so you can keep reshaping/resizing to fit your needs.

[image]

[image]