# how can i make a half cylinder?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

here is a picture of the shape i would like to make in blender i have no clue how to even begin making it. what i want to know is how to make this shape in blender so i can use it for a project im doing. i tried adding a cylinder but then i could not figure out how to get the cylinder to be cut in half.  [image]

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26477/how-to-make-a-half-cylinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perhaps simpler way is to use the cylinder primitive.

Add that to your scene, 
[image]
then in wireframe (Z key), and from the front view, 
[image]
delete half vertices:
[image]
[image]
[image]

then rebuild top/bottom faces selecting the edge loop and pressing F key

[image]
[image]

on both sides

then you get

[image]

Another way could be to use a boolean modifier, too.

Comment: You should next time add this answer to rest of answers in the linked question, this one will become just a duplicate.

Comment: Ah, yes that makes quite sense... but since my method is not in the linked answer (and its duplicate) if the OP of this answer wants to choose _this_ new answer as the one "solving better"  his question... how can/should he do? I'm a bit puzzled by all this linked (sometimes nested) previous answers...