# How to make a curved triangle with exact measurments

Tags: modeling

firstly, i would like to apologise for the title, it may not be on point.

secondly, i would like to thank all of you who always help and answer noob questions. I have learned a lot form you guys.

here is my question:

i am trying to make a small triangle box, to 3d print. And that box needs to have a sliding door. 
the first problem i am facing is getting an homogenous rounded edge on the hypotenuse, which makes it difficult to model the sliding door.

[image: my ugly triangle box]

[image: the sliding door]

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: ...why don't you start from a quarter of cylinder? please use the image tool to embed images... I had to fix your links to make images clickable

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19172/how-to-create-quarter-cylinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to get the results you want is to start with a cylinder. Simply add a cylinder, choose triangle fan as the cap fill type, and from top view delete the mesh you don't need (3/4 of it). Then fill the 2 flat sides (one face each) and you're done.