# Where is cap fill type?

Tags: interface

I have been just recently starting out with blender and have reached a point where I was trying to make a triangle with rounded corners.

I was following this [tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98766/how-to-make-a-curved-triangle-with-exact-measurments) when I got to the part where it says "set cap fill type to triangle". I am using Blender 3.2 and I have been looking for this setting literally everywhere for 20minutes, still can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the *Operator* box just after you've created the shape, the box will disappear if you make a new action though (if you've just clicked somewhere you can still bring it back with <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>).

[image]